# Switch case with regex in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I made a Ruby script which uses a regex to cut line from a file and paste it in a new file. That part works fine. Now I want to enter a region into the console and the output should show me just the region which i typed in before.

For example I'm looking for this "ipc-abc-01" and type abc in, now it should show me all entries with abc.

```ruby
found = 0
words = [] 

puts "Please enter a word to search the list"
input = gets.chomp

#Open text file in read mode 
File.open("list.txt", "r+") do |f|

  f.each do |line|
   if m = line.match( /\b#{input}\b/i )
      puts "#{m[0]} "
      # ... etc.
      found = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It won't find `ipc-zhb790-r-br-01` because the regex is `\bzhb\b` so it's looking for a word boundary after `zhb` but find `7` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? this searches all strings by user given input in regex form that is case insensitive..

```
words = []

print "Please enter a word to search the braslist: "
input = gets.chomp

#Open text file in read mode 
File.open("braslist.txt", "r+") do |f| 
    f.each do |line| 
        words += line.split(" ").grep(/#{input}/i)
    end
end 

puts "#{words.length} words found!"
puts words
```

Comment: Also you can use an array to hold your other search criteria instead of only one from the user input. Then nest a each loop that will grep each search criteria from the array.

Answer (score 0):

To match all words containing `zhb` in:
  `zhb440 zhb440 izhh550 ipc-zhb790-r-br-01`
you can use:

```
\S*?(?:zhb)\S*

if line =~ /\S*?(?:zhb)\S*/
    match = $~[1]
else
    match = ""
end
```

[See the DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/z1qWIrDYSU)

Comment: ok thanks but i got also something like wip or sgl and more how can i filter them without an if loop for every word

Comment: i got something like that in the txt file 
zhb440
zhb440
izhh550 and im looking for the zhb's and just want to print the zhb's out how can i do that?

Comment: This is very heavily Perl-accented Ruby here. A more Ruby solution would be `match  = line[/.../].to_s` which avoids a lot of the `if`, `=~` and bizarro `$~` stuff.